# Why emitter @current-items not working for v-data-table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to console.log visible items in table but @current-items emitter not working, please help me to figure out why?
**I have vuetify: "1.3.11"**

```js
methods: {
        currentItems(val) {
           console.log(val) // the method is not called for some reason
            this.test = val
           console.log(this.test)
        }
}
```

```html
        <v-data-table
            @input="updateSelected"
            v-bind="calculatedTableProps"
            ref="dataTable"
            :pagination.sync="localPagination"
            :value="selected"
            :headers="localHeaders"
            :items="filteredItems"
            :headers-length="headerCount"
            :total-items="totalCount"
            :loading="tableLoading"
            class="big-data-table"
            :class="tableFitContent ? 'table-fit-content' : ''"
            :hide-actions="customActions"
            v-scroll:[scrollTarget]="onScroll"
            @current-items="currentItems"
        >
```

Comment: You need to use `@click` to trigger the method call, if the method and v-data-table are in the same component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@current-items` event does not seem to exist in Vuetify 1.x. Take a look at [the docs of the v-data-table](https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables) for Vuetify 1.5.24.